# Compile errors when when importing C++ headers (import loop) in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl, powervr-sgx

I know in order to avoid these type of compiling errors a way to solve this is to use @class MyClass in the header instead of import. Then #import the header in the implementation but this is not working for me.

The compile errors does not appear in the header file where I am importing the class but in the imported class' header.

The error I get is

class PVRShell --> Redefinition of 'PVRShell' as different kind of symbol.

Just in case I am using PowerVR and GLView(OpenGl) in my project.

Any ideas of how can I solve this compile error?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file extension from .m to .mm.
You have to do that if your class use Objective-C++.

Comment: my C++ extension is .cpp not .mm. I tried to rename it to .mm also and did not work. If I do not loop the import it builds and runs as .mm also.

Comment: I fixed this by importing the classes from the implementation file. not the header. I don't know what is the reason behind this.